# Instability in 2D steady state heat equation with variable thermal diffusivity

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, heat-equation, finite-differences

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration with this issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to numerically solve the steady state heat equation in 2D (x,y) with variable thermal diffusivity. I started with the following equation:

$$ 0 = \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \left( \alpha \mathbf{\nabla}U\right) $$

$$ 0 = \alpha \nabla^{2}U + \nabla\alpha\cdot\nabla U $$

$$ 0 = \alpha \left[ \frac{\partial^{2}U}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2}U}{\partial y^{2}} \right] + \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x} \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial y} \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$$

Where $U$ is the temperature and $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity, both are functions of x and y.

I used a centered difference scheme for both the temperature $U$, and the thermal diffusivity $\alpha$. Solving for $U_{i,j}$ I get:

$$ U_{i,j} = \frac{1}{4} \left[\left(1 + \frac{\alpha_{x}}{2\alpha}  \right)U_{i+1,j}+\left(1-\frac{\alpha_{x}}{2\alpha}\right)U_{i-1,j} +\left(1+\frac{\alpha_{y}}{2\alpha}\right)U_{i,j+1} + \left(1 - \frac{\alpha_{y}}{2\alpha}\right)U_{i,j-1} \right]$$

Where the finite difference forms of the first derivative of thermal diffusivity are:

$$ \alpha_{x} = \frac{\alpha_{i+1, j} - \alpha_{i-1, j}}{2} $$

$$ \alpha_{y} = \frac{\alpha_{i, j+1} - \alpha_{i, j-1}}{2} $$

I initialize a 2D grid with a starting temperature (100) and set a boundary condition on one side (200). As I iteratively solve for $U$ many of the initial values of $U$ drop below 100 (99.99999999999997) during the first iteration and eventually the iterations diverge (i.e. become negative).

Before I show the code that I wrote to implement this here is a list of things I've tried:

- Modified the thermal diffusivity matrix to have all the same values (i.e. constant thermal diffusivity). This actually worked and the solution converged. As one expects the derivative terms of thermal diffusivity are zero. This makes me think that it has something to do with the finite difference representation of the thermal diffusivity.
- Created all the variables using double precision (128). The iterations still became unstable.
- I tried both rescaling the thermal diffusivity by a single value and also a linear transformation to decrease the range of values. The iterations still became unstable.

Here is the snippet of the Python code I wrote to solve this:

```
import numpy as np

def partial_k(k):
    k_x = 0.5 * (k[2:, 1:-1] - k[:-2, 1:-1])
    k_y = 0.5 * (k[1:-1, 2:] - k[1:-1, :-2])

    return k_x, k_y


def delta(u, k, k_x, k_y):
    # Propagate with central-difference in space
    u_new = u.copy()
    u_new[1:-1, 1:-1] = 0.25 * (
        (1 + 0.5 * k_x / k[1:-1, 1:-1]) * u[2:, 1:-1] +
        (1 - 0.5 * k_x / k[1:-1, 1:-1]) * u[:-2, 1:-1] +
        (1 + 0.5 * k_y / k[1:-1, 1:-1]) * u[1:-1, 2:] +
        (1 - 0.5 * k_y / k[1:-1, 1:-1]) * u[1:-1, :-2]
    )

    return u_new


# Files and directories
fname = 'some/file/with/thermal/values'

iter_out = 500

# Get Friction surface from raster
k = np.load(fname)

# Find partials of thermal conductivity
k_x, k_y = partial_k(k)

# Number of rows and columns
n_rows = np.shape(k)[0]
n_cols = np.shape(k)[1]

# Max number of iterations
max_iters = 5001

# Convergence tolerance
tol = 1e-5

# Set the boundary conditions
t_cool = 100
t_hot = 200

# Initialize temperature matrix
u_0 = t_cool * np.ones((n_rows, n_cols))

# Set boundary conditions
u_0[:, -1] = t_hot

# -----------
# Calculation
# -----------
for i in range(max_iters):

    u_update = delta(u_0, k, k_x, k_y)

    delta_u = np.abs(u_0 - u_update)

    if delta_u.max() < tol:
        break
    else:
        u_0 = u_update.copy()
```

Comment: Centered difference scheme, maybe you could make use of some regularizer. But those are much easier to implement in implicit methods.

Comment: @mathreadler, thanks for the comment. I'm not very familiar with regularizers. I will have to look into this.
Do you think it is a stability issue and not an issue with the formulation of finite difference scheme or coding? If it's stability would it be better posed as an implicit scheme rather than an explicit scheme? Can explicit schemes be unstable for steady state? Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: I have mostly worked with implicit schemes, so I can probably not give so much help on this one.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks. Do you have any good references for formulating the matrix for the implicit scheme?

Comment: Wait a minute, there is no time variable? Most heat equations I have worked on have had partial time derivatives in them. Is this the case when this time derivative has become 0 everywhere or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just considering the steady state solution (i.e. partial wrt to time goes to zero).

Comment: Ah, ok.. Sad then I can't make nice animations. I like animations. :'(

Comment: There is one step missing between your maths and your code. After discretization, you have obtained a system of linear equations involving the values $U_{i,j}$. How are you solving this linear system? It appears that you are using some iterative scheme, maybe the Jacobi method. Since you're not sure whether the problem is with the discretization or the iterative solver, you should try a more reliable solver first (a direct matrix-vector solve if you can, though even Gauss-Seidel would be better than Jacobi). If you still get negative values, then you need to change your discretization.

Comment: Rahul has good ideas. If you get a specific matrix-vector form, then you can check the matrix condition and make sure the problem has a unique solution and nice numerical properties so you will be able to solve it, for example with Tikhonov regularization or changing discretization or something thirdly.